# Send email to single recipient via mailchimp

Tags: asp.net, mailchimp, email

I need to send an email to single person, as my earlier emailer is not more with me, so I need in to use MailChimp.

Any code and help regarding the MailChimp? I am using asp.net.

Comment: Hi Maunil. We here at stackoverflow encourage you to try doing it yourself. And if you run into some problems, then you should post a question with information and code sample of what you tried.

Comment: I done R&D last day , but no luck yet,, so help would be appreciable

Comment: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582367-API-Wrappers

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Subscribe Button in your aspx page

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe"  CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnSubscribe_Click" runat="server" Text="Go" />
```

**In CodeBehind**

Along with the Keys you need to have MailChimp dll which need to be referenced to your project

```
protected void btnSubscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       // Keys for Mail chimp , when you signup in their site 
       // there you can get these keys and i stored them in webconfig
        string apiKey = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpApiKey"]);
        string listId = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpListId"]);

        var options = new List.SubscribeOptions();
        options.DoubleOptIn = true;
        options.EmailType = List.EmailType.Html;
        options.SendWelcome = false;

        var mergeText = new List.Merges(txtSubscribe.Text.Trim(), List.EmailType.Text)
                {
                    {"FNAME", "webruster"},
                    {"LNAME", "Web"}
                };
        var merges = new List<List.Merges> { mergeText };

        var mcApi = new MCApi(apiKey, false);
        var batchSubscribe = mcApi.ListBatchSubscribe(listId, merges, options);

        if (batchSubscribe.Errors.Count > 0)
            //     Console.WriteLine("Error:{0}", batchSubscribe.Errors[0].Message);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSubscribe, btnSubscribe.GetType(), "subscribe", "alert('Given email address is already subscribed, thank you!')", true);
        // ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSubscribe, btnSubscribe.GetType(), "subscribe", "alert('"+ batchSubscribe.Errors[0].Message + @"')", true);

        else
            //      Console.WriteLine("Success");
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnSubscribe, btnSubscribe.GetType(), "subscribe", "alert('You are subscribed to newsletter successfully.')", true);




    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //   ErrorLogger.ClientErrorLogger(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is meant by list id ?

Comment: _Each MailChimp list has a unique List ID that integrations, plugins, and widgets may require to connect and transfer subscriber data. The List ID is generated by our system when the list is created and cannot be changed._ [Source](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/managing-subscribers/find-your-list-id)